# How do I install the google-talkplugin?

Tags: 64-bit, google-talk

How do I install the Google talk plugin so I can use gtalk and Google Plus?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting in Ubuntu 11.10 multi-arch is used for applications that formerly used `ia32-libs`.

gtalk & Google plus are the same plugin. They are are comprised of a 64-bit plugin plus a 32-bit daemon - and use the deprecated ia32-libs, it will be up to Google to update their package at some point.

Under Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 users should continue to use the 64-bit .deb available from http://www.google.com/chat/video on amd64 systems, as the 32-bit .deb cannot be used without additional modifications to the system at this time.

Once downloaded the plugin can be installed by either:

1. Clicking open in the browser;
2. Open the file manger, navigate to `~/Downloads` and double click on the google plugin deb file;

Either method will open the Software Center to complete the installation.  If you receive a dependency error, make sure you have selected Universe in your software sources.

Comment: Didn't work for me under 12.04.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a hacky way to handle this:

1. Download the 64-bit .deb from: http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/talkvideo/hangouts/
2. Create a tmp dir:

   ```
   mkdir tmp
   ```
3. Extract the contents of the .deb to the tmp dir:

   ```
   dpkg-deb -x google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb tmp
   ```
4. Extract the control files:

   ```
   dpkg-deb --control google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb tmp/DEBIAN
   ```
5. Fix the dependency:

   ```
   sed -i "s/lib32v4l-0/libv4l-0/" tmp/DEBIAN/control
   ```
6. Repackage the .deb:

   ```
   dpkg -b tmp google-talkplugin_current_amd64-fixed.deb
   ```
7. Install the fixed version:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_amd64-fixed.deb
   ```
8. Go to Google to fix their .deb file for 64-bit Oneiric: http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/

Comment: This also didn't work for me under 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

For ubuntu 14 - there seems to be a bug in the software center, so you'll need to download the file from google servers:

```
https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin
```

and then use the command line to install the .deb file. Browse to downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

Install .deb file via command line:

```
sudo dpkg -i <google-talk-file.deb>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install from the official Google repo following [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-google-talk-ubuntu-official-repository/):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list'
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-talkplugin
```